# Use Puppeteer / Chrome debugging protocol to install Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

If I have an existing Google Chrome window open, I'd like to tell puppeteer to open a new tab instead of opening a new window. Is there a way to do that? is there some option or flag I can pass to puppeteer to accomplish this?

I have:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

  const args = puppeteer.defaultArgs().filter(arg => String(arg).toLowerCase() !== '--disable-extensions');

  const b = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
    args: args.concat(['--remote-debugging-port=9223'])
  });

  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint:  b.wsEndpoint(),
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('chrome-extension://hfnplgaapcnjblpebnhibfcdfllkpaaf/dist/index.html');


})();
```

on the last call (`page.goto()`) I get an error.

```
Error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

I think it's because I need to install/enable the Chrome extension in the Chromium browser. Does anyone know how to use the Chrome debugging protocol to install Chrome Extensions?

Comment: Have you considered filing an issue at the repository at GitHub?

Comment: this is what I have so far: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1788

Comment: Have not tried puppeteer. This is a list of Chromium flags https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/. Undocumented flags exist as well. To auto open `DevTools` you can use `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` though encountered a bug using the flag see [How to disable chromium focus to new tab when clicking link?](https://askubuntu.com/q/904782). `--custom-launcher-page` is listed as a flag which "Specifies the chrome-extension:// URL for the contents of an additional page added to the app launcher." not sure if that meets your requirement. Have you read the linked docs and repo?